# Unreferenced, NULL fields on sales_flat_order

Tags: orders, database, ee-1.13

I'm working on an extension that I inherited from somebody else. It makes references to `sales_flat_order.customer_note` and `sales_flat_order_payment.po_number`, but they are always empty or null. Are they used for anything?

Comment: this are using in which file in xml, phtml or php file?

Comment: They're being retrieved by the respective objects using magic methods in a PHP class, but that's irrelevant. I'd just like to know how to populate those fields either on the frontend or in the admin in a native EE instance.

Comment: `sales_flat_order` is a table name and `customer_note` field name check your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`po_number` can be filled in via the front end or admin section when the payment method `Purchase Order` is activated.

It is the link between a [Purchase Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchase_order) and the order assigned in Magento.

*Note: I am still not 100% sure what a purchase order is but that is what the field is for*

Answer (score 1):

`sales_flat_order.customer_note` is at least used when you create a order in the admin backend and is filled with the comment you give.

The `po_number` is used in backend only, too. As far as I can find.